# how do I implement a jump address table in MIPS64?

Tags: mips, mips64

I have to implement a switch/case statement using a jump address table in MIPS64 to run it in winmips64. I have search around for how to do this but the solutions are for mips32 using pseudo instructions that are not supported in winmips64. This is the code that i have so far.

```
.data

F: .word 0
G: .word 10
I: .word 5
H: .word 15
J: .word 6
K: .word 4

prompt: .asciiz "Case: "

CONTROL: .word32 0x10000
DATA:    .word32 0x10008

.text

main:
    ld $s0, F(r0)
    ld $s1, G(r0)
    ld $s2, H(r0)
    ld $s3, I(r0)
    ld $s4, J(r0)
    ld $s5, K(r0)


    lwu $s6,CONTROL(r0)
    lwu $s7,DATA(r0)

    daddi $t0,r0,4; ascii output
    daddi r1,r0,prompt 
    sd r1,($s7)
    sd $t0,($s6)

    daddi $t0,r0,8  ; read input
    sd $t0,($s6)
    ld $s5,($s7)



    daddi $t2, $zero, 4
    slt $t3 , $s5 , $zero # $t3 =1 if k < 0
    bne $t3 , $zero , Exit # if k < 0 go to Exit
    slt $t3 , $s5 , $t2 # Test if k < 4
    beq $t3 , $zero , Exit # if k >= 4 go to Exit

    dadd $t1 , $s5 , $s5
    dadd $t1 , $t1 , $t1

    ;load into $t4 address of table

    dadd $t1, $t1, $t4 # $t1 = address of JumpTable [k]
    lw $t0, 0($t1) # $t1 = JumpTable [k]
    jr $t0

L0: dadd $s0 , $s3 , $s4 # f = i + j
    j print
L1: dadd $s0 , $s1 , $s2 # f = g + h
    j print
L2: dsub $s0 , $s3 , $s4 # f = g - h
    j print
L3: dsub $s0 , $s1 , $s2

print: 
    daddi r24,r0,1; integer output
    sd $s0,($s7)
    sd r24,($s6)
Exit:
    halt
```

Comment: A jump table is just an array of doublewords (or whatever the native address size happens to be). Access the elements like any other array, and use `jr` to do the jump once you have the address.

Comment: How do i add the address of the labels to the array and how can i access them back? I think that's the logic of what is supposed to happen. I've seen the la for 32bits and dla for 64bit instructions but those don't work in winmips64.